# mkdir -p is "ambiguous" what should I do?

Tags: command-line, mkdir

When I type in "mkdir -p" windows powershell spits out that the parameter p cannot be used because it is ambiguous, any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you providing a valid path name?

Comment: I'm following a course; [link](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/appendix-a-cli/ex8.html) and   cannot work out why mkdir -p won't run. I checked I was home, changed the directory to temp and then typed in mkdir -p i/like/icecream and got the error

Comment: What version of Powershell?

Comment: Windows PowerShell Version 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to runs as an alias,
  -p is ambiguous because it could be either of the `-Path or -PipelineVariable` arguments for New-Item.try below

```
mkdir -path Home\first\second
```

it will may be work..

Comment: Thank you, it seems to have worked that way! I would however like to discover whether this error occurs with everyone (in which case, should the sites' instructions be changed) or just me.