# How can I create a file with command line in Windows? in a not-yet-exist folder before the command as the command is to execute both file and folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, touch, mkdir

I am trying to make a file with the command line with the form of

```
mkdir -p /path/to/directory && touch /path/to/directory/file.txt
```

so in my case it will be like this: `mkdir -p layout && touch layout/layout.ejs`, but I receive a message

> `touch` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The folder has been made successfully but the file is not.

Comment: This perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/create-an-empty-file-on-the-commandline-in-windows-like-the-linux-touch-command

Comment: [Create an empty file on the commandline in windows (like the linux touch command)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30011267/995714), [windows equivalent to touch](https://superuser.com/q/1784460/241386), [Windows equivalent of the Linux command 'touch'?](https://superuser.com/q/10426/241386), [Equivalent of Linux `touch` to create an empty file with PowerShell](https://superuser.com/q/502374/241386)

Comment: As I want to make a file in a directory not already exist before will not  be possible

Comment: if you have the answer, please give me the command line to be executed

Comment: you didn't show any research effort: [What is equivalent to Linux `mkdir -p` in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/905226/995714), [powershell equivalent of linux "mkdir -p"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47357135/995714), [mkdir -p is "ambiguous" what should I do?](https://superuser.com/q/854570/241386), [How to recursively create subfolder in each folder of a directory in CMD](https://superuser.com/q/1192289/241386), [How to create multiple sub-directories in one command from windows command prompt?](https://superuser.com/q/1002348/241386)

Comment: Replace `touch` with `type`, as `touch` is a non-Windows command and `type` is the Windows equivalent to create an empty file with 0B

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do. You can send text in CMD to a file [using the redirect command, `>`](https://www.howtogeek.com/306682/how-to-save-the-command-prompts-output-to-a-text-file-in-windows/). E.G.

```
echo "hello world" >c:\temp\layout.ejs
```

Sends this:

```
"hello world"
```

to the file `layout.ejs` in the `C:\temp` folder.

Comment: Thank's but this didnot solve the problem also,As I need one command line to make adirectory and a file in the same timing

Comment: two steps: `c:\temp\glorp` and `echo "hello world" >c:\temp\glorp\layout.ejs`. Use `&` or `&&` to do it on one line. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd **Read a tutorial,** e.g., https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/command-line-commands-cli-tutorial/

Comment: I do want to make an empty file for now and I try your answer the system cannot find the folder specified and try to add dir in the first got the the system cannot find the file specified can you show me the command which already working with you